# I used selenium 4.16.1 and i get this exception when i run in azure pipeline - SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session

Tags: java, azure, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, cucumber

```
I use this method to open chrome:
```

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

        chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to windows os only
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); 
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless=new");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("force-device-scale-factor=0.75");

        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

I try many thinks like : WebdriverManager / Chrome options [![enter image description here]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykPNO.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykPNO.png)